# iOS8.1: Keyboard Notifications not fired on iPad

Tags: ios8, uikeyboard

I'm trying to listen to UIKeyboardWillShowNotification and UIKeyboardWillHideNotification in order to move UITextField up or down. The notification handler is not being invoked, not to mention frame changes.

Things work fine before iOS8. Stranger it is, I have exactly same code working fine on iPhone with iOS8.1. Any ideas about keyboard notifications on iPad with iOS8?

Answer (score 0):

If the iPad keyboard is split or undocked, you won't get WillShow/WillHide notifications.

Comment: it is a normal keyboard triggered by a normal text field. i just did a test on a new, empty project. i drag a text field to the storyboard, and run the app. On iphone, I got notification; on iPad, no. I suppose this is a bug from Apple.